# Make an UI element transparent to mouse events

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a lot of UI elements placed inside a canvas. Some of them are not supposed to handle mouse events while they can overlap with and cover other elements that must handle mouse events. When a mouse event occures, I want it to pass throuh all the elements that are not supposed to handle it to reach an element that might be covered by them, but can handle it. Is there any way to do this?

I need to do this in a Silverlight project, but also interested in WPF solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just set the `IsHitTestVisible` property to false